# How to tell powershell dir command to look a folder up?

Tags: windows, powershell

The folder structure is:

```
--root
--root\source-code\
--root\powershell-scripts\
```

I need the method below that is inside the `\powershell-scripts` folder to target files inside `\source-code`:

```
function Test($param)
{
    dir -Include ASourceCodeFile.txt -Recurse |
    % { SomeMethod $_ $param }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: From where is the function being run?

Comment: You only declare 1 parameter in your function signature (`$param`), but supply 2 parameter arguments when you call the function recursively (`$_` and `$param`) - what's up with that?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks that was a typo I made an edit

Comment: @Eris it's run inside `powershell-scripts`

Answer (score 2):

The `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable contains the path of the directory in which the current script is located. Use `Split-Path` to find its parent (your `--root`) and `Join-Path` to get the path to the `source-code` folder:

```
Join-Path -Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent) -ChildPath 'source-code'
```

`$PSScriptRoot` was introduced in PowerShell 3.0

Comment: @DougPeters Not sure I understand. It's an automatic variable (like `$true`,`$false`, `$?` etc.) - ie. it's always *there*

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, my PS skills are terrible.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but maybe still helpful for someone:

Directory structure :

```
MyRoot\script\scriptrunning.ps1
```

config:

```
MyRoot\config.xml
```

to read the xml file from `scriptrunning.ps1`:

```
[xml]$Config = Get-Content -path "${PSScriptRoot}\..\config\config.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a script in `--root\powershell-scripts\` and you want to reference something in `--root\source-code\` or say get-content you can do this:

```
cd --root\powershell-scripts\
get-content '..\source-code\someFile.txt'
```

The `..\` references the parent directory which contains `\source-code\` and then you reference or pull in file or scripts from that directory.

Comment: That would change the current directory, though, so if I wanted to run the script several times I would have to  manually enter the same directory each time. How would you just tell the script in my question to begin the search a folder up than the current one?

Comment: `get-content '..\*'` pull anything in one folder up.  or `get-content '..\source-code\*'` the `cd <path>` was just an example to show the current directory of your script that is running.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` which Mathias mentioned is a great thing to use if your script moves around you dont have to update file paths it will just use where ever your scrip is run from so if you push the code to a server or something you dont have to update paths to match the new directory structure

Comment: how would you re-write the script above to perform what you describe here?

Answer (score 0):

this was a trick that I used in vbs that I converted to PS...

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent

$a = $scriptPath.split("``\``") for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $a.count-1 ; $i++){  
    $parentDir = $parentDir + $a[$i] <br>
    if($i -lt $a.count-2){$parentDir = $parentDir + "``\``"}

}

Write-Output $parentDir
```